# deinit on UIView Subclass not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have made the simplest possible subclass of UIView in playground and simply created an instance and then set that instance to nil. Super simple. deinit is not being called. Anyone have any ideas?

```
class MyView: UIView {
    deinit {
        print("View deinit")
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    deinit {
        print("Controller deinit")
    }
}

var firstView: MyView?
firstView = MyView()
firstView = nil

var myController: MyViewController?
myController = MyViewController()
myController = nil
```

This outputs the following:

```
Controller deinit
```

Where is "View deinit" ??

Comment: Seems like odd code - as in sample code for the *real* issue - to me. After copy/paste (with a second copy/paste into `viewDidLoad`) into a new single view project **both** worked. Any chance you can post code that the issue you're facing can be replicated? Maybe include what you're trying to do? EDIT: I do understand that this might be a playground issue only.

Comment: I tried it on playground and i got the same thing. Although I can't imagine why this would be the case. as @dfd pointed out this could just be a playground issue

Comment: You very much misunderstood me. Your words: *'I have made the simplest possible subclass of UIView in playground..."* Question: Have you tried it in a playground? I gave you my basic way of trying in a project, and could not duplicate it." Now, if *your* code works in a **project** where all code is in it's own class or the base controller's `viewDidLoad`, then I'm hoping you can provide more detail.

Comment: Hey, those were *my* words! :P
Thanks for the response. You are right that this was something I discovered while trying to learn the ins and outs of NSMapTable in a playground. I wasn't getting the memory management behavior I desired from that, and was trying to track down the issue, leading me to this sub-issue. (I was trying to map UIViews to UIViewControllers using all weak references as part of a custom ContainerViewController implementation). Will try this in a project and see how it goes. If all is well, I don't think I will ever trust playgrounds again for memory management issues.

Comment: Can confirm: the code works when run in a real project. Thanks for the sanity check guys. If one of you wants to reply with a solution placing the blame on playgrounds, we might as well mark this one down for posterity to help the next soul from tearing his hair out!

Comment: Don't know for sure, but I suspect the reason is very simple, the view object is instantiated and displayed in the results sidebar, so is retained even after being set to nil in the editor. The playground environment is doing a addSubview(yourView) for you so it is retained by the editor's view hierarchy.